# Python 3 code stops at HTTP error and I can't figure out how to handle it

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib, splinter

I'm trying to scrape links from the website https://www.usyouthsoccer.org/clubs/club-directory/. Initially, the code broke at the 30th link, so I tried to handle the exception error with urllib HTTPError. Now, the script just stops running at the 30th link. I checked that specific url and it is a bad link. I just want to move past it in the loop, but I'm having trouble with the work around. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from splinter import Browser
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError

executable_path = {"executable_path": "chromedriver"}
browser = Browser("chrome", **executable_path, headless=True)
url = 'https://www.usyouthsoccer.org/clubs/club-directory/'

zipcode_input = 'CT_Main_0$txtLocation'
search_button = '//*[@id="CT_Main_0_btnSearch"]'
dropdown = '//*[@id="CT_Main_0_drpMiles"]/option[5]'

zip_codes = [64015]

team_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in zip_codes:
    try:
        print(f'\n{x}\n')
        url = 'https://www.usyouthsoccer.org/clubs/club-directory/'
        browser.visit(url)
        browser.fill(zipcode_input, x)
        browser.find_by_xpath(dropdown).click()
        browser.find_by_xpath(search_button).click()
        html = browser.html
        soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        dallas_urls = soup.find_all(class_="more")


        counter = 1
        for url in dallas_urls:
            print(f'Link {counter} of {len((dallas_urls))}')
            counter += 1
            back_url = url['href']
            front_url = 'https://www.usyouthsoccer.org'
            total_url = front_url + back_url
            browser.visit(total_url)
            my_html = pd.read_html(total_url)
            details_pd = pd.DataFrame(my_html[0])
            details_pd.columns = ['Cols', 'Vals']
            df = details_pd.T
            df.columns = df.iloc[0]
            df.drop('Cols', inplace = True)
            contacts_pd = pd.DataFrame(my_html[1])
            if len(contacts_pd.index) == 1:
                df['Contact_Title'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0,0]
                df['Contact_Name'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0, 1]
                df['Contact_Email'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0, 2]
            elif  len(contacts_pd.index) == 2:
                df['Contact_Title'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0,0]
                df['Contact_Name'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0, 1]
                df['Contact_Email'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0, 2]
                df['Contact_Title2'] = contacts_pd.iloc[1,0]
                df['Contact_Name2'] = contacts_pd.iloc[1, 1]
                df['Contact_Email2'] = contacts_pd.iloc[1, 2]
            elif len(contacts_pd.index) == 3:
                df['Contact_Title'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0,0]
                df['Contact_Name'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0, 1]
                df['Contact_Email'] = contacts_pd.iloc[0, 2]
                df['Contact_Title2'] = contacts_pd.iloc[1,0]
                df['Contact_Name2'] = contacts_pd.iloc[1, 1]
                df['Contact_Email2'] = contacts_pd.iloc[1, 2]
                df['Contact_Title3'] = contacts_pd.iloc[2,0]
                df['Contact_Name3'] = contacts_pd.iloc[2, 1]
                df['Contact_Email3'] = contacts_pd.iloc[2, 2]


            team_df = pd.concat([team_df, df])
    except HTTPError as err:
        continue
```

Comment: Maybe you can use the `try` and `except` functionalities in python.

Answer (score 2):

Put your try statement inside of the nested for loop.  Right now it looks like if you have a HTTP Error it is stopping the entire for loop - instead of continuing through the for loop.

```
for url in dallas_urls:
    try:
        print(f'Link {counter} of {len((dallas_urls))}')
        counter += 1
        back_url = url['href']
        front_url = 'https://www.usyouthsoccer.org'
        total_url = front_url + back_url
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(total_url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError:
        print ('Error')
        continue
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks for your help